# How to condense a declaration of multiple strings?

Tags: c++, string

Currently if I am defining a bunch of different strings, I'm doing it like this;

```
string a = "A";
string b = "B";
string c = "C";
string d = "D";
string e = "E";
```

Is there an easier way to define all of these strings in one line?

Comment: Why do you think that is easier? Because it is less lines? If this is what you need I think this is the best readable..

Comment: Sorry, by easier I meant more compact and concise. Easier on the eyes shall we say

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do

```
string a = "A", b = "B", c = "C", d = "D", e = "E";
```

even if I prefer one declaration by line.

or maybe, you want an array ?

```
string strings[5] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
```

and then use `strings[0]` to `strings[4]`.

Comment: Both of these are useful! I think the top line was what I was looking for, but the use of an array is also interesting, thanks!

Comment: Better use `std::array<std::string, 5> strings  {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};`. (Or `std::vector` (Or `std::deque`))

Answer (score 4):

You could also do:

```
string a = "A",
       b = "B",
       c = "C",
       d = "D",
       e = "E";
```

Technically it is a one liner but I find this easier to read than:

```
string a = "A", b = "B", c = "C", d = "D", e = "E";
```

Answer (score 4):

An easier way to do this would be

```
String letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

Then calling the appropriate letter by using

```
letters[0]; //"A"
letters[1]; //"B"
//etc.
```

Alternatively, you could use the value of a char to get the right index of the string containing the letters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Array, Vector or List if you have number of related strings like you defined. . .